# How to flatten a digital signal whose baseline jumps up and down with Python?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, ekg

I'm analyzing the electrocardiogram (EKG) built-in dataset from SciPy, a segment of which looks like below:
[image: Screenshot of Scipy EKG from a Kaggle notebook]

One problem with the data above is that the baseline of the EKG jumps up and down a lot. If you're not familiar with EKGs or heartbeat analysis, they're supposed to be flat with a few spikes of the "QRS complex" (AKA the actual heartbeat), like below:

[image: An image of a fake EKG from the American Heart Association]

Medical device companies that make EKG monitors use some flattening and filtering functions to make EKGs smoother and easier to read, since natural human body movements are unavoidable and will cause the EKG signal to jump around as shown above. But I don't know which filters/functions they use.

How can I use SciPy or write a custom function to flatten the SciPy EKG dataset above?

## What I have tried

I have tried reading the [SciPy documentation for signal processing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html), but have not yet found any functions that "flatten" data or bring it to baseline. I'm a novice in digital signals processing and want to know if there is a better or official way to do this.

I have tried shifting the values up or down by some moving average, but there's no way that simple addition or subtraction of Y-values is the correct way. That is too hacky.

Thanks for your help.

## Question clarification: fixing "baseline wandering"

Another user in the comments (Christoph Rackwitz) suggested a high-pass filter. While Googling high-pass filters, I found an image from a [research paper on ECGs](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-example-of-baseline-wandering-removal-showing-a-raw-signal-from-Lead-I-b-filtered_fig4_225040955):

[image: EKG with baseline wandering adjustment]

They said the first image had "baseline wandering," which is what I'm really trying to answer with this question. How do I fix baseline wandering?

## Two useful research papers

Considering the research paper I mentioned in the last section, as well as [another one I just found about fixing baseline wandering in ECGs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8708403/), I'll read these and see what I find.

Comment: Which spikes are the signal and which are the noise? What generated the data? Do you know what is causing the noise? Have you tried high- and/or low-pass filters? Having an idea of the cause of the noise is important. For example, I was once working with microphone data and had to remove the 60Hz signal caused by the mains power supply.

Comment: I actually just looked at the scipy electrocardiogram documentation for the example data and it says, `Finally, examining the power spectrum reveals that most of the biosignal is made up of lower frequencies. At 60 Hz the noise induced by the mains electricity can be clearly observed.` So understanding different aspects of the signal is important.

Comment: highpass. that's the term. research it a little. and maybe with a bit of a bandstop on 50/60 Hz (mains voltage). -- ECG usually does "common mode rejection" in hardware, i.e. electrically. such a signal should not arrive at the ADC.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristophRackwitz. This is the kind of detail I was looking for. However, I'm not quite looking to smooth out the curves (though that will be useful in later steps). What I want is to bring all of the QRS curves down to zero. Right now, it's looking like when you give a child a writing assignment on a lined page and they start writing characters higher and higher and don't stay on the line. The words just start floating up. In the same way, the EKG is jumping up and down and I want to flatten everything.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I added more detail to the original post. Looks like what I'm trying to fix is called "baseline wandering."

Comment: yes, this "baseline wandering" can be dealt with by subtracting a lowpass. there might be lowpass filters that are more suitable. literature review should yield some comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a showcase of some lowpass filters.

You'll want to read up on "causal" filters vs non-causal filters, as well as the difference between FIR and IIR.

Loading the data:

```
signal = scipy.datasets.electrocardiogram()
fs = 360 # say the docs
time = np.arange(signal.size) / fs # for plotting only
```

Explore the signal:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(15, 15))
axs[0].plot(time[30000:31000], signal[30000:31000])
axs[1].plot(time[30000:40000], signal[30000:40000])
axs[2].plot(time, signal)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[2].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 1]

Trying a few filters:

```
# Butterworth, first order, 0.5 Hz cutoff
lowpass = scipy.signal.butter(1, 0.5, btype='lowpass', fs=fs, output='sos')
lowpassed = scipy.signal.sosfilt(lowpass, signal)
highpassed = signal - lowpassed

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], signal[30000:32000])
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], lowpassed[30000:32000])
axs[1].plot(time[30000:32000], highpassed[30000:32000])
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylim([-3, +3])
axs[1].set_ylim([-3, +3])
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 2]

```
# take note of these coefficients:
>>> scipy.signal.butter(1, 0.5, btype='lowpass', fs=fs, output='ba')
(array([0.00434, 0.00434]), array([ 1.     , -0.99131]))
# and compare to the following...
```

```
# Almost the same thing, different formulation: "exponential average"
# y += (x - y) * alpha  # applied to each value X of the signal to produce a new Y

alpha = 1/100 # depends on fs and desired cutoff frequency
lowpassed = scipy.signal.lfilter([alpha], [1, -(1-alpha)], signal)
highpassed = signal - lowpassed

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], signal[30000:32000])
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], lowpassed[30000:32000])
axs[1].plot(time[30000:32000], highpassed[30000:32000])
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylim([-3, +3])
axs[1].set_ylim([-3, +3])
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 3]

```
# the first two filters were "causal", i.e. only using past samples.
# downside: lag, phase shift, i.e. the lowpass doesn't quite match/track the signal.
# "non-causal" filters can use future samples.
# this allows to remove the phase shift but the processing introduces a delay instead.
# this delay is irrelevant for offline processing or if it's considered "small enough".
# the following are non-causal.
```

```
# median filter. interpret peaks as outliers, so this reveals whatever can be considered "baseline".
# can be causal if the kernel window only covers the past but that introduces lag (noticeable when the signal drifts actively).
# might need another pass of smoothing, on the median filter, before subtracting.
# median filtering CAN be cheap, if using the right data structure. scipy implementation seems less smart, takes noticeable time.

lowpassed = scipy.signal.medfilt(signal, kernel_size=fs+1)
highpassed = signal - lowpassed

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], signal[30000:32000])
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], lowpassed[30000:32000])
axs[1].plot(time[30000:32000], highpassed[30000:32000])
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylim([-3, +3])
axs[1].set_ylim([-3, +3])
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 4]

```
lowpassed = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d(signal, sigma=0.2 * fs, order=0)
highpassed = signal - lowpassed

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], signal[30000:32000])
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], lowpassed[30000:32000])
axs[1].plot(time[30000:32000], highpassed[30000:32000])
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylim([-3, +3])
axs[1].set_ylim([-3, +3])
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 5]

Answer (score 1):

To add to Christoph Rackwitz's quite extensive answer (from which I pinched the plotting code), you can also use a non-causal (phase preserving) IIR high pass filter to remove the baseline drift. This is effectively the same as using a lowpass to compute the moving baseline and then subtracting it from the original signal:

```
from scipy import signal, datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ecg = datasets.electrocardiogram()
fs = 360 
time = np.arange(ecg.size) / fs 
[b,a] = signal.butter(4, 0.5, btype='highpass', fs=fs)
filtered = signal.filtfilt(b, a, ecg)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
axs[0].plot(time[30000:32000], ecg[30000:32000])
axs[1].plot(time[30000:32000], filtered[30000:32000])
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylim([-3, +3])
axs[1].set_ylim([-3, +3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Be sure to use `filtfilt` and not `filt` (or a variety like `sosfilt`) or else the nonlinear phase response of an IIR filter (e.g. a butterworth filter) will change the shape of your signal and perhaps ruin further QRS analysis. An FIR filter will not do this, but it will also time shift your original signal by as many samples as you have filter coefficients---which will be many (as many as 400+) for a nice tight frequency response.